# Remove duplicate arrays

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, multidimensional-array

I have following arrays :

```
$t[0] = array('one'=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
$t[1] = array('two'=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
$t[2] = array('one'=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
$t[3] = array('three'=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
```

I want to remove duplicate arrays from above arrays, the result should be :

```
$t[0] = array('one'=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
$t[1] = array('two'=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
$t[2] = array('three'=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
```

Thanks

Comment: first hit on google using your question title?!

Comment: sheesh, some people think that question should be done for the good of Stackoverflow. I think the opposite, questions are for the good of the users over stackoverflow.   Duplicates questions are bad, however silly (or novice) questions are not bad.

Comment: @mag - Where is the question here??? It is a request for code... Not one question mark in sight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand what you want to do is remove duplicate **keys** from a **multi-dimensional** array.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($t as $array) {
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if(!array_key_exists($k, $new_array)) {
            $new_array[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$t[0] = array('one'=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
$t[1] = array('two'=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
$t[2] = array('one'=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
$t[3] = array('three'=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));

$array = array();
foreach ($t as $key=>$value) {
    if (!in_array ($value, $array)) {
        $array [$key] = $value;
    }
}
print_r ($array);
```

Comment: Straight forward answer though.

Comment: This is not an answer - there was **no question**. It was a request for someone else to do his work... And sadly... they got it...

Comment: I have googled about that, no good result, thats why I'm here

Comment: some people is saying "f*ck noob", we only want ultra complex questions not simple questions.  :-/

Comment: (though you're right that people should try it themselves before asking)

Comment: You're right, your question wasnt that straightforward. I've updated my code, it works now. But next time, try to tell us what you already tried, why that didnt work and formulate your exact question

Comment: Thank you Jeroen ! You rock !

Comment: it does not work for this :
    $t[0] = array('one'=>array('a'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
    $t[1] = array('two'=>array('b'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
    $t[2] = array('one'=>array('c'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));
    $t[3] = array('three'=>array('d'=>2,'b'=>3,'c'=>2,'e'=>4));

    $array = array();
    foreach ($t as $key=>$value) {
        if (!in_array ($value, $array)) {
            $array [$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    print_r ($array);

Comment: Why do you suddenly not accept the answer anymore? If you look at the array you just send in the comments, there are no duplicate arrays. My answer does exactly what you asked...